# Can we shape a magnetic field in a way, where we can align some magnetic objects in a specific way?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to create a specific pattern of magnetic field, where the interaction between the objects (objects that  responds to magnetic field) and magnetic field create forces in specific way and direction to align and orient them in a specific place or in a specific pattern?

Comment: Yes. *objects* are electrons and they can align ,respond to **B** while orbiting in a atom.

Comment: no i mean real objects not atoms

Comment: I may try to write an answer but can you please just let me know a little more about your *objects* and what it is really that you want?

Comment: Like small little metal balls for example

Answer (score 0):

Just like *inertial mass* responds to the gravitational field (in Newtonian sense), charged particles respond to electric fields so, in the same way, electric currents (more strictly the moving particles) respond to magnetic fields. But as you know current always flows through a loop, therefore, we prefer to define a quantity called *magnetic moment* as the product of the area which the loop surrounds with the current and we assign it the direction perpendicular to the area of the plane. $$ \mathbf{\mu} = \mathbf{A} \times I $$ Now, it's more convenient to use the magnetic moment as something which responds to the magnetic field. This is being done, let's move to three types of materials

1. **Diamagnetic** :- No intrinsic magnetic moment and hence a sudden magnetic field will induce a magnetic moment that will be in the opposite direction to the original field. Therefore, diamagnetic material will be repelled by the magnetic field.
2. **Paramagnetic** :- Some little intrinsic magnetic moment and hence a sudden magnetic field aligns it in its direction. Therefore, this material is attracted by magnetic fields.
3. **Ferromagnetic** :- Appreciable intrinsic magnetic moment and all of the domains are in same direction (for iron nails, nickel etc.) and hence they too get aligned by the external magnetic field. Therefore, they too get attracted by the magnetic field.

The matter is that *diamagnetism* and *paramagnetism* are very weak and most of the time imperceptible. It may astonish you that even a wood (which is diamagnetic) gets repelled by the external magnetic field but it's not noticeable as the effect is very minimal.

> Is it possible to create a specific pattern of magnetic field, where the interaction between the objects (objects that responds to magnetic field) and magnetic field create forces in specific way and direction to align and orient them in a specific place or in a specific pattern?

Yes, of course. Take some ferromagnetic material like iron nails and a strong bar magnet, place the bar magnet on the table where numerous irons nails are randomly arranged and after some time you will find a pattern like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOtv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOtv.png)   . This pattern is seen because magnetic field lines start from north pole and end at south pole and ferromagnetic iron nails respond appreciably to this external field.

I hope it helps.